# MongoDB find Query working on local machine but not working on production server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-ec2, mern

This is query to getschedule on particular day. This query working fine on my machine.
But on porduction server i am getting empty array. I hosted my app on AWS
`const schedules = await Schedule.find({ docId, day })`

I tried
`const schedules = await Schedule.find({ day })` and `const schedules = await Schedule.find({ docId })` both working fine on production server.
But `const schedules = await Schedule.find({ docId, day })` is giving empty array

Comment: 99,9% that it's about difference in data

Comment: try retrieving data without filter and then check whether record you're looking for exists on both systems or no

Answer (score 1):

I solved issue.
It was due to Change in timezone, Time was changing, so there was no matching time.